# PHP modules with its description/functions

Tags: php

Does anybody have the list of PHP modules that can be installed on a Linux box, along with its description/functions ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [PECL](http://pecl.php.net) and [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/packages.php).

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check out your distribution installer (yum, apt-get etc.), obtain a list of all available packages and grep for php